# How to fix reactjs warning: each child in an array should have a unique prop...?

Tags: reactjs

I am running my reactjs app and getting a warning in my console:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop. Check the render method of `AppointmentsContainer`

My component looks like this:

```
export default class AppointmentsContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        //todo remove
        //debugger;

        let appointments = mockData.data;

        return (
            <div>
                //loop through the appointments
                {appointments.map(function(a,i){
                    //todo remove
                    //console.log('testing=a', a);
                    return <p><Appointment key={i}/></p>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I am passing in a key now but still the warning comes up? How can I fix this?

Comment: The key should be on the p tag, not the appointment tag

Comment: Prefer a unique property of the appointment object over the `i` index for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the key in the `p` element instead of `Appointment`. Since `Appointment` is the only child of `p`, it does not need a key.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a key will not perform any extra functionality but still to remove the warning you can replace your code with

```
  return <p  key={i}><Appointment/></p>
```

Or you can keep change your code to

```
 <div>

                //loop through the appointments
                {appointments.map(function(a,i){
                    //todo remove
                    //console.log('testing=a', a);
                    return <Appointment key={i}/>
                })}

            </div>
```

And in Appointment component you can access it as

```
<div>
<p>{this.props}</p>
</div>
```